# Properly wrap new domain object instance with $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

As a follow up to [$resource to return array of [OO] objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523343) how to properly wrap new domain object instances from $resource

```
app.factory('NoteResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {

  var res = $resource('http://okigan.apiary.io/notes/:id', null, ...);

  res.newInstance = function() {
    return angular.extend(new Note(), res);
  };
}
```

NoteResource.newInstance() shall return object with standard $save/$update methods.

Best to modify the [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/AVLQItPIfoLwsgDzoBdK?p=preview) and watch [**traffic**](http://docs.okigan.apiary.io/traffic) then "New note" button shall work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Here is a way you can continue incorporate your `Note` constructor into your `$resource` service...

Add a new instance method to the object returned from the factory:

```
res.getNew = function(){
  var newNote = new Note();
  newNote.id = undefined; // new note doesn't have id set
  newNote.checked = undefined; // don't need this data passed to server?
  angular.extend(newNote, res);
  return newNote;
}
```

This method modifies an instantiated `Note` object (to remove ID and other data that doesn't need to be passed to the server when creating a new note) before merging it with the `$resource` service and returning that object to the caller.

Call that method from your controller assigning its return value to a local variable. You can also modify its properties from the controller:

```
var note = NoteResource.getNew();
note.title = 'Eat a lot of junk food';
```

Call the `save` method on the `note` object, passing itself as the sole parameter:

```
note.save(note).$promise.then(function() {
  $scope.notes = NoteResource.query();
  $scope.newNotes = [];
});
```

Watch in dev tools and notice that this does result in a JSON payload being sent with the POST containing your `note` properties (which your previous solution did not).

Hopefully this solution ticks off your box for enforcing a model without having to using a factory in an unintended manner.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/knywTMrHXctokkjbRg5s?p=preview)

Comment: this does NOT work as returned instance does not expose standard angular functions ie. $save. try in http://plnkr.co/edit/AVLQItPIfoLwsgDzoBdK?p=preview

Comment: I was responding to the limited scope of the code sample in your question. If I have the chance I will help you review your code. For the meantime, I should say that factories are meant to be singletons in Angular for a reason and you're bound to run into issues if you violate that convention.

Comment: This forces posting a possibly invalid state to the backend. The reason to merge the two is to have centralized [injection] point how to construct the domain object. You're taking advantage of this simple example, but basically your line `NoteResource.save({}, {title: 'This...'})` duplicates the logic of constructing the object (which is generally more complex than shown in plunker)

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-resource-for-data-models seems interesting. btw uses provider instead of factory

Comment: Read over the top few answers of this question for counter-arguments to the `new Service()` approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626075/non-singleton-services-in-angular It also provides some alternatives. I understand that you're looking to emphasize the *model* more than is often the case. I don't want to turn this into a forum, so I'll leave things here but I may take another stab at your demo sometime later with another approach for you to consider.

Comment: @okigan Check out my recent update for an implementation using an instance method like the one you described in your question.

Comment: I think this covers my question -- marking this as answer.   I got another approach in the updated plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/AVLQItPIfoLwsgDzoBdK?p=preview). Also, I reviewed posts and info about new on factory object -- seems quite normal to do so

Answer (score 1):

Posting my solution for reference:

Latest demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/AVLQItPIfoLwsgDzoBdK?p=preview

Key item to the solution is to wrap returned json objects into javascript objects
with correctly **[set prototype](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)**.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngResource']);

//
function Note() {
  this.id = '<new id>';
  this.title = '<new title>';
  this.checked = false;
  this.spellCheck = function() {
    // imagine spellchecking logic here
    this.checked = true;
  };
}

app.factory('NoteResource', function($resource) {

  var wrap = function(_) {
    // forward declaration -- function redefined below
  };

  function extend(item) {
    return angular.extend(new Note(), item);
  }

  var url = 'http://okigan.apiary.io/notes/:id';
  var res = $resource(url, null, {
    create: {
      method: 'POST',
      transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter) {
        var item = angular.fromJson(data);
        var headers = headersGetter();

        // also handle HTTP 201 response
        var extra = {
          location: headers.location
        };
        var model = wrap(item);
        angular.extend(model, extra);
        return model;
      }
    },
    query: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true,
      transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter) {
        var items = angular.fromJson(data);
        var models = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
          models.push(wrap(item));
        });
        return models;
      }
    },
    get: {
      method: 'GET',
      params: {
        id: '@id'
      },
      transformResponse: function(data, headersGetter) {
        var item = angular.fromJson(data);
        var model = wrap(item);
        return model;
      }
    }
  });

  res.url = url;

  wrap = function(data) {
    var T = Note;
    // read up on http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html
    T.prototype = res.prototype;
    var instance = new T();
    angular.extend(instance, data);
    return instance;
  };

  res.newModel = function() {
    return wrap({});
  };

  return res;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, NoteResource) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.notes = NoteResource.query();
  $scope.newNotes = [];

  $scope.spellCheckAllNotes = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.notes, function(note) {
      note.spellCheck();
    });
  };

  $scope.newNote = function() {
    var note = NoteResource.newModel();
    note.title = 'Buy cheese and bread for breakfast.';
    $scope.newNotes.push(note);

    note.$save().then(function() {
      $scope.notes = NoteResource.query();
      $scope.newNotes = [];
    });

  };
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't put yourself in a position where you `new` your factories.