# AngularJS - Expected response to contain an object but instead got an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create an object in Angular.

Here is my factory

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('Order', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/products?id=:id/orders?id=:orderId', { id: "@_id" }, {
            query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
            update: { method: 'PUT'}
        });
    });
```

Here is my controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('OrderCtrl',
  function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, Order, Auth) {
    $scope.myOrder = Order.get({"id": 1, "orderId": 1});
  }
});
```

Here is my routes.js file in my server directory

```
app.use('/api/products', require('./api/product'));
```

In my api/products directory, I have an index file

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./product.controller');

var router = express.Router();
// Endpoints for products
router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.create);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.patch('/:id', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

// Endpoints for product - order definitions
router.get('/:id/orderDefinitions', controller.showOrderDefinitions);
router.post('/:id/orderDefinitions', controller.addOrderDefinitions);

// Endpoints for product - orders
router.get('/:id/orders', controller.showProductOrders);
router.get('/:id/orders/:orderId', controller.showIndividualProductOrder);
router.put('/:id/orders/:orderId', controller.updateIndividualProductOrder);
router.delete('/:id/orders/:orderId', controller.deleteOrder);

module.exports = router;
```

Here are the two endpoints I'm trying to access

```
router.get('/:id/orders/:orderId', controller.showIndividualProductOrder);
router.put('/:id/orders/:orderId', controller.updateIndividualProductOrder);
```

Here is my controller

```
exports.showIndividualProductOrder = function(req, res) {
  Product.findById(req.params.id, function (err, product) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!product) { return res.send(404); }
    Order.find({productId: product._id, _id: req.params.orderId}, function (err, order) {
      console.log("found individual product order", order);
      if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      if(!order) { return res.send(404); }
      // Get product's order
      return res.json(order[0]);
    });

  });
};

// Update an individual order for a product
exports.updateIndividualProductOrder = function(req, res) {
  Order.find({productId: product._id, _id: req.params.orderId}, function (err, order) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!order) { return res.send(404); }

    var updatedOrder = _.merge(order, req.body);
    console.log("updating order", order, updatedOrder);
    updatedOrder.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, product);
    });

  });
};
```

And yet, I still get this error

> Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array (Request: GET /api/products?id=1/orders?id=1)

I used `Postman` to test the API endpoints, and the JSON output is an array. But in my factory, I clearly stated that I didn't want an array with the `isArray` option.

Comment: `get` and `query` are different methods in $resource. You specified `isArray` on `query` but not `get`. Also setting to false suggests will be object. End result you still have a mismatch of object types. Simplest might be make `isArray:true` on query and use that method instead of get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used Postman to test the API endpoints, and the JSON output is an array. But in my factory, I clearly stated that I didn't want an array with the isArray option.

With the `isArray` flag you don't specify what you *want*, you specify what is to be expected on that particular API endpoint.

If you don't want an array, change the backend code, but if it is an array, then use `isArray: true` in the configuration.

Edit: you can use the `tranformResponse` property to specify a converter function for the data, which would enable you to use an endpoint returning an object, but still use a resource method configured for an array with `isArray:true` (and vice versa), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23524686/4083826) for an example.